# How many Blades can I have at once?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

In the “Manage Blades” menu, how many different Blades I can have at once? Is there a maximum number of Blades I can have before having to release a few?

Additionally, what happens if you try to bond with a blade after reaching the maximum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note: Everything I'm about to say is *probably* true, but I cannot say with 100% certainty.)

Your maximum number of blades is based on your Merc Group level. At level 3, this amount is 96 blades. At level 4, this amount is at least 109 (as I have 108 and can bond more). Rare blades *do not* count towards this limit. (A blade is a "rare blade" if it appears in the Blade Album.) This limit is *party-wide*; IE, with a limit of 96, if Rex has all 96 blades, there's no space for blades bonded to anyone else (except rares, of course).

If you try to bond a Common, Rare, or Legendary core crystal while at the limit, the game will inform you that you can't bond with any more blades. However, this does *not* occur with unique core crystals, such as Roc's or the Beastly core crystal, since they are guaranteed to contain a (specific) rare and thus not count towards your limit.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum number of Blades you can have depends on the ranking of your mercenary group in Garfont. Once you reach this maximum, you cannot bond any more Blades until you release Blades or increase the ranking of your mercenary group.

Comment: It should be noted that this is a _per person_ limit and not a total limit.

Comment: @Seiyria This is incorrect. When I hit the bonded blade limit, I'm blocked from summoning blades with *any* character.